# Yii2 dropdownlist onchange Redirect to URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I would like this code to redirect to /user/create
How do I do it?

```
echo Html::beginForm();

echo Html::activedropDownList(
    $model, //name
    'COMPANY_ID',  //select
    $companyList, //items
    ['onchange'=>'this.form.submit()'] //options
);

echo Html::endForm();`
```

Comment: Besides pointing the correct page (like @jorgen said) i cant seee why your code would not work. In your User/create action, dont you get the id? How are you calling the id (in that action)? can you show us?

Comment: $COMPANY_ID = $_GET['COMPANY_ID'];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the form will have `action = ''` and `method = 'post'`. You must change that:

```
echo Html::beginForm(['method' => 'get', 'action' => 'user/create']);

echo Html::activedropDownList(
    $model, //name
    'COMPANY_ID',  //select
    $companyList, //items
    ['onchange'=>'this.form.submit()'] //options
);

echo Html::endForm();
```

You can find more info in the doc [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#beginForm%28%29-detail).

**UPDATE**

By the way, you should recheck the way you are retrieving the id in you user/create page. Just to check how the get parameter is being sent, i would recommend you make a `var_dump ($_GET)` in that action. IE:

In the default ContacForm if i change the method to 'get', when i print `var_dump ($_GET)` and submit it will show:

```
array (size=3)
    'r' => string 'site/contact' (length=12)
    'ContactForm' => 
        array (size=5)
        'name' => string 'c' (length=1)
        'email' => string 'teste@teste.com.br' (length=18)
        'subject' => string 'safd' (length=4)
        'body' => string 'asfas' (length=5)
        'verifyCode' => string 'eaxpzwp' (length=7)
        'contact-button' => string '' (length=0)
```

The inputs that i need are inside of an array "ContactForm". And that's because my form is coming from the model `ContactForm.php`. So, keep that in mind in users/create to call the id correctly. Probably will be something like:

```
$get = Yii::$app->request->get(); //retrieve all get params in the url, even the route.
if (isset($get['ContactForm'])) { //Replace by the name of the form's model.
    $COMPANY_ID = $get['ContactForm']['COMPANY_ID'];
}
```

Let me know if i wasnt clear on something and i will update the answer for you.

Comment: If I use this line:echo Html::beginForm('method' => 'get', 'action' => 'user/create'); I get an Error: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: Yea, i forgot the `[]`, my bad. Updated the answer.

Comment: Another thing: I don't know what will be best in your project, but, just for you know, you also use the `post` method with that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the form to be processed by users/create, you have to define a action in the beginForm function

`echo Html:beginForm(['users/create'])`

Check http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#beginForm()-detail for more info.

Comment: Hi Jorgen.Thank you very much. This works. But, the id was not submitted, how can I pass the ID?

Answer (score 0):

...
'onchange' => 'window.location = "/user/.."';
...

Comment: Thank you!It does work. The Problem now is, how do I pass the COMPANY_ID?

Comment: maybe as a query
/user/create?id=""